# Make An Line Chart Using Array - D3.js

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js, charts

I want to make an line chart using d3.js with php.
My array is like as below:

```
{"x_axis":["xyz","abc","pqr"],"y_axis":["1","2","2"]}
```

I want to put whole x_axis array on x-axis and y_axis array on y-axis of line graph.

Please advice me for the same.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are lots of examples of line charts with D3, e.g. [this one](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245).

Comment: Yes it's true but i have no knowledge about d3.js.
So can you help me for make an line chart using above array.
Thank you

Comment: Now i have convert my array like as also : 
[{"x":"xyz","y":"1"},{"x":"abc","y":"2"}].
If anyone is ready for the help then use this array also.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use d3.scale.ordinal and map function to plot the values on axis. See [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0ym1WKkkmIJMcdDSLESB?p=preview) for example.

```
      var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeBands([0,300],0.01);

var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
.rangeBands([0,300],0.01);


xScaleMappedValues = xScale.domain(data.map( function(d) {console.log(d.x); return d.x;}))
yScaleMappedValues =  yScale.domain(data.map( function(d) {console.log(d.y); return d.y;}))
```

EDIT :
To plot data points against those values

```
svg.append("g")
.attr("class","datapoint")
.selectAll(".gCircle")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("g")
.append("circle")
.attr("cx", function(d) {console.log(d.x); return xScale(d.x)  +  xScale.rangeBand()/2 })
       .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.y) +  yScale.rangeBand()/2; })
       .attr("r",5)
```

Comment: Thank you for reply but now i want y axis as dynamic and draw the point for "xyz" to 1 and "abc" to 2 then what i need to?

Comment: do you mean change x axis data?

Comment: Yes on X Axis "xyz" and on Y-axis ="1" and draw the point on graph at point 1 and same as abc also.

Comment: see the edited plnkr (http://plnkr.co/edit/0ym1WKkkmIJMcdDSLESB?p=preview). Accept this answer if it solves your problem and ask a new question if you have run into more problems and have more questions.